# How do I add a newline using printf?

Tags: bash, printing, terminal

How do I add a new line to a print command using printf?

```
printf "I want this on a new line!"
```

I thought it would be something like this but it didn't work

```
printf "/n I want this on a new line!/n"
```

Answer (score 49):

To write a newline use `\n` not `/n` the latter is just a slash and a n

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, but is it possible to create a single command with multiple words? So for example, change the ls command to list files?

Comment: You probably can't use two words with a space because it will think of it as the command "list" with the argument "files". list-files could probably be aliased. Try Googling around for terminal aliases on your OS. "ls" is shorter though and easier to remember.

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
printf '\n%s\n' 'I want this on a new line!'
```

That allows you to separate the formatting from the actual text. You can use multiple placeholders and multiple arguments.

```
quantity=38; price=142.15; description='advanced widget'
$ printf '%8d%10.2f  %s\n' "$quantity" "$price" "$description"
      38    142.15  advanced widget
```

Comment: Thanks, I had mine unquoted and it wasn't working. Also, here is an example if you need to do a process substitution too, replace 'date' with any other command. `printf "$(date) \n\n"`.

Comment: @ElijahLynn: You should separate formatting from data: `printf '%s\n\n' "$(date)"`

Comment: Nice, that is good separation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sample program to understand it better:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char ch;
long lo;
int in_;
double dou;
float fl;

int main() {
   
scanf("%d %ld %c %f %lf",&in_,&lo,&ch,&fl,&dou);
printf("%d\n%ld\n%c\n%f\n%lf\n",in_,lo,ch,fl,dou);
    
}


sample input :3 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493
sample output:
3
12345678912345
a
334.230
14049.304930000
```