# How to printf vertically?

Tags: c, printf

This is my code. My point is to take string input and count how many of each letter occurs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    int c1;
    int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, e=0, f=0, g=0, h=0, i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0, m=0, n=0, o=0, p=0, q=0, r=0, s=0, t=0, u=0, v=0, w=0, x=0 , y=0, z=0;

    while (( c1=getchar()) != EOF)
        if (isalpha(tolower(c1)) != 0) {

            if (tolower(c1) == 97) {  // Character = 'a'
                a += 1;
            }

            else if (tolower(c1) == 98) { // Character = 'b'
                b += 1;
            }

            else if (tolower(c1) == 99) { // Character = 'c'
                c += 1;
            }

            .
            .
            .

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Next I want to printf result in vertical. Could you give me some hints. For example,

input: ABC---Ddhhh

output:

```
       *
   *   *
****   *
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: just printf each char separately , or use newline?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693431/how-do-i-add-a-newline-using-printf

Comment: Can you please show your code for how you're printing? Or do you not have that yet?

Comment: Avoid using *MagicNumbers* use `'a'` when you mean '`a'` not `97`, `'b'` when you mean `'b'`, not `98` and so on. See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be a struggle learning, it's important to spend time learning and not simply copy/pasting lines of code to have a big program. The best code is the briefest code that achieves the objective.

As others have said, the *contiguous* alphabet should cause you to use a *contiguous* **array** of counters, not individual variables. (One typo and your results will be wrong.) Nesting `isalpha(tolower(c))` is not needed. And, you've shown how you might count, but not shown code that would output the desired results.

This is for you to study, learn and grow as a coder.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Try to write functions; blocks of code that do what you want in compartments
void countAndGraph( char *str ) {
    int max = 0, cnt[26] = { 0 }; // initialises 'max' and 26 counters

    for( char *p = str; *p; p++ ) // as long as there is a character
        if( isalpha( *p ) ) {     // if it is alphabetic
            int i = tolower( *p ) - 'a'; // convert ASCII character to value 0-25
            if( ++cnt[ i ] > max ) // increment the right counter and test against max
                max = cnt[ i ]; // 'max' - the ceiling - keeps getting higher
        }

    for( ; max; max-- ) { // lower the ceiling
        for( int i = 0; i < 26; i++ ) // for 26 alphabetic characters
            putchar( " *"[cnt[i]>=max] ); // output ' ' or '*' if count at/above ceiling
        putchar( '\n' ); // newline
    }
    puts( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ); // reference alphabet string
    puts( str ); // the string that's been analysed
    puts( "" );
}

int main() {
    char *tst[] = { // three test strings to demonstrate
        "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs",
        "Sally sells seashells by the sea shore",
        "I wish I was what I was when I wished I was what I am now",
    };
    const size_t nTst = sizeof tst/sizeof tst[0];

    for( size_t i = 0; i < nTst; i++ ) // count and graph each of the strings
        countAndGraph( tst[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

```
              *
    *         *
    *  *      *  ****
**************************
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs

                  *
                  *
    *      *      *
    *      *      *
    *      *      *
*   *  *   *      *
*   *  *   *      *     *
**  *  *   *  *  ***    *
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Sally sells seashells by the sea shore

                      *
        *             *
        *             *
*       *             *
*      **         *   *
*      **         *   *
*      **         *   *
*   *  **    *    **  *
*  **  **   ***   **  *
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
I wish I was what I was when I wished I was what I am now
```

Now that you have this code, an exercise would be to print the bar graph in ascending/descending order. Don't stop with this one version; push it to a new educational experience.

```
                         *
                         *
                         *
                         *
                        **
                       ***
                      ****
                 *********
             *************
            **************
          ****************
         *****************
        ******************
fzcxqpjkuvywnbmdgrloshiate
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
```

Comment: `"A quick brown fox .... "` is actually 2-characters shorter for the same full alphabet `:)` Nicely done.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin AND, I made the fox jump over multiple dog**s**, too! `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have more than one or two variables that do the same thing, it is time to use a data structure; in this case, an array. You will want something like

```
int counts[26];
```

instead of twenty six different variables, and only have one statement instead of 26 different `if` clauses. Then you can say

```
counts[lower(c1) - 97]
```

instead of `a`, `b`... `z` (after checking that `lower(c1)` is one of the letters).

The way to print the output is based on these insights:

- The number of lines above the alphabet is the highest number in `counts` (let's call it `maxcount`). It would be `3` in your example.
- For each line, there is a `*` if that letter's count is at least `maxcount - line` (i.e. in 0th line, there is a `*` if there is at least `3 - 0` counts of that character), otherwise there's a space.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just print one at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    int c1;
    int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, e=0, f=0, g=0, h=0, i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0, m=0, n=0, o=0, p=0, q=0, r=0, s=0, t=0, u=0, v=0, w=0, x=0 , y=0, z=0;
    // I might do an array here, so you can loop through later.
    int letters[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};


    while (( c1=getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(tolower(c1)) != 0) {

            if (tolower(c1) == 97) {  // Character = 'a'
                a += 1;
                letters[0]++;
            }

            else if (tolower(c1) == 98) { // Character = 'b'
                b += 1;
                letters[1]++;
            }

            else if (tolower(c1) == 99) { // Character = 'c'
                c += 1;
                letters[2]++;
            }

            .
            .
            .

        }
    }
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < 26; ii++) {
        printf("%d\n", letters[ii]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `char lc = tolower(ci);` and  `letters[lc - 'a']++;` and forget the `if .. else if ... ... else`? You can initialize `int letters[26] = {0};` and avoid a lot of typing `:)`

Comment: Ah true, I forgot about initializing. Haven't done C in a while. I left the if else's because the original question had that, and felt like remaining close to what they had in their question would provide more insight to them specifically. I agree though, the else if's are cumbersome.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Could you please decribe this code 'letters[lc - 'a']++;' for me, like how it works? I search on the internet but still don't understand. What is "-" sign in the middle using for?

Comment: How does this produce the requires output (the ASCII art histogram chart with vertical bars)?

Comment: When you create `char lc = tolower (ci);` you store the lowercase representation in `lc`. Using the [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/), you can see the lowercase `'a'` has the ASCII value `97`. So when you use `lc - 'a'` as the index you automatically map the correct character to the correct index. Take `'b'` for example, looking at the ASCII Table, you can see `'b' - 'a'` would give you the index `1` (correct), `'a' - 'a'` index `0` ... `'z' - 'a'` index `25`. A great way to simplify things.

Comment: For a full explanation of what is frequency array is, and how to use it, a fuller explanation is provided in answer to [How to remove duplicate char in string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255183/3422102). An example related to characters is [Find most frequent letter in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65462132/3422102). There many many ways you can apply this same logic. Which is what @Amadan did in his answer, just using `tolower(ci) - 'a'` as the index. See my *MagicNumber* comment under the original question.